# Google Earth Engine - Remove geometry fields from FeatureCollection for export to table

Tags: geometry, google-earth-engine, table

How do I remove the geometry fields from this feature collection? They are not necessary and give me a messy table in excel.

```
// Add reducer output to the Features in the collection.
function protected_areas (image, select_country) {var pas = image.reduceRegions({
  collection: select_country,
  reducer: ee.Reducer.frequencyHistogram(),
  scale: 30,
}); return pas.map(function(feature){
  var dict = ee.Dictionary(feature.get('histogram'))
  feature = feature.set(dict)
  return (feature)})
} // appends output from histogram into separate columns

// export function
function export_table (table, description, date) { 
  var em = Export.table.toDrive({
    collection: ee.FeatureCollection(table),
    description: region+'_'+description+'_'+date,
    folder: region
});return em}
```

link to code: https://code.earthengine.google.com/dba0dca5d0395d981ae3e1e97126e49a

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can remove the geometries by setting them to "null", like this (https://code.earthengine.google.com/e8812348780874f1ac9d54a080fc4071):

```
// Add reducer output to the Features in the collection.
function protected_areas (image, select_country) {var pas = image.reduceRegions({
  collection: select_country,
  reducer: ee.Reducer.frequencyHistogram(),
  scale: 30,
}); return pas.map(function(feature){
  var dict = ee.Dictionary(feature.get('histogram'))
  feature = feature.set(dict).setGeometry(null)
  return (feature)})
} // appends output from histogram into separate columns

// export function
function export_table (table, description, date) { 
  var em = Export.table.toDrive({
    collection: ee.FeatureCollection(table),
    description: region+'_'+description+'_'+date,
    folder: region
});return em}
```

Answer (score 2):

An additional alternative to remove the geometries, specifically the ".geo" field that can remain in your final table, is by using the 'selectors' parameter like this:
https://code.earthengine.google.com/d6701745330f0d1d71d68f71c406cf59

Here, the selector parameter is set up to use a list of strings, which are going to be the columns of your final table

```
// export function
function export_table (table, description, date, selectors) { 
  var em = Export.table.toDrive({
    collection: ee.FeatureCollection(table),
    description: region+'_'+description+'_'+date,
    folder: region,
    selectors: [selectors]
});return em}
```